# Why is this question on-hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold

As you can see, the question [ClassNotFoundException when running Spark application with spark-submit [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550595/classnotfoundexception-when-running-spark-application-with-spark-submit) is on-hold for the following reason:

> "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

However, the user mentioned the exception (to answer the "why") and showed part of the code necessary to reproduce it (the "how", if we want to consider a command as a way to reproduce a problem). For me the code posted was enough, and I think that every user who knows how to use/run Spark agrees. The problem itself is super dumb, there is no reason for any Java/Scala/Python code snippet.

Just saying, but I have seen worse questions (AKA homeworks/code challenges with a "do this for me" attitude) with a relatively high score. I do agree with you that new users should be "trained" since the early stages on how to write good questions (after all, I had to modify the title and the layout), but the question itself sounds okay - no scala/java code is necessary.

Comment: Yeah, a stack trace with no code. This definitely *smelled* like a bad question. It is possible that 4/5 voters flipped the switch purely for that reason. But the first guy does seem to at least be *familiar* with Spark, judging by his top tags. Maybe he voted on an early, unedited form of the question, where the non-existent "no effort" would have been a better close reason.

Comment: The code in this case is the command. There is no need for Java/Scala code - if you know how to use spark-submit. It's like calling "java -jar file/to/class.java" (the option "-jar" wants a jar, not a .java file). No code, but you can help the person, because it's just a stupid mistake - whatever the reason is (RTFM).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Presumably, the close voters did not notice that there was a command in there.

This probably happened because that command is in a section labelled "Output".

I think it's best to edit the question a little:

> I do this:
>
> ```
> [command]
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> [Stack trace]
> ```

In this way, it becomes immediately clear that there is a command, and not just a stack trace.

Editing also makes it eligible for re-opening. Be sure, if you decide to edit the question, to leave an informative edit summary.

Comment: Oh jeez. I scrutinized the question pretty carefully after reading this question, and I *still* didn't see that. It all looked like a stack trace to me.

Comment: It took even me a good few seconds to notice the first line in the output (*after* the edits) was actually a command. But maybe I just don't spend enough time in a terminal...

Comment: @Cody Gray: You and me both.

Comment: I did as you suggested - now it should be more readable. I think that I got used to read so many "ugly" questions, that this particular question looked OK to me :D

Comment: @Markon I've seen the edit suggestion, and voted to approve it. I've also left a comment on the question, to inform the OP that the question is being discussed here.